# Prestashop database changes - Backend caching

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

i changed in the TABLE "ps_products" some informations about my product visbility.

The field "visibility" can be "none","both","category" or "search".
The field defines the visibility in frontend.

i changed a few thounsand products from "both" to "none", but in my backend all products are still set to "both".

Caching is disabled and force compiling is activated.

Changing the field via Backend works fine.

I need to know how to change the field via SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prestashop the table "ps_product" hase some same fields as "ps_product_shop"

The field "visibility" (enum) is in both tables and need to be updated in both.

redundant... i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

I have a multishop in prestashop. 
Shop1 and Shop2 (duplicate shop). 
My default shop is Shop1. I think prestashop keeps the default shop1 in ps_products. 
Where as any new shop you add is added in ps_product_shop.

For me, ps_product_shop has shop1 and shop2 (can have shop3, ..4,..5) . 
So when I edit price of products in ps_product. Nothing happens on the front end.
The data in ps_product_shop does not change maybe to keep other shops from being affected by the change. 
To actually see the prices change on the front.I had to change the price in ps_product_shop

Make sure related tables are changed.